# Why when I try to reverse a sentence and output into the console, there is a space between the output and the input?

Tags: c, for-loop, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

char nova[500];  

int main() 
{ 
    fgets(nova, 500, stdin);
    for(int i = strlen(nova); i <= strlen(nova); i--)
    {
    putchar(nova[i]);
    } 
    getch();
}
```

This is a program that allows you to input anything, and then it will print out that thing but instead it will be reversed.

It should be like below.

Input:

```
Hello World!
```

Output:

```
!dlroW olleH
```

However, the output has a space above it, which makes it like this.

```
!dlroW olleH
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `fgets` includes the training newline.

Comment: C or C++ pick one, don't mix

Comment: `i <= strlen(nova)` that's not right.... and the index `i=strlen(nova)` is actually one past the end of the string. In C arrays are zero-based. Thus the last index is length-1.

Comment: Re `for(int i = strlen(nova); i <= strlen(nova); i--)`: What? That would continue the loop into negative `i`. Did your program print additional characters, beyond what you have shown? Is that the actual code? It also prints the null terminating character.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How do I fix it?

Comment: By [removing the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).